# LinkedList and TreeMap: compareTo or equals?

Tags: java, linked-list, treemap

I need a clarification regarding the use of TreeMap and LinkedList. Do these two structures use compareTo or equals?

In particular, TreeMap keeps the order in the keys, I suppose using the compareTo method of the class defined for the keys. However, when using get, do they use compareTo or equals to see if the key you pass is contained?

I have the same doubt for contains and getIndex inside LinkedList.

Comment: How about writing a piece of code and trying it yourself?

Comment: `TreeMap` will use `compareTo`, because it needs to know how to sort the keys. Note that this same method will be used for object identity as well, so make sure its implementation is consistent with `equals`/`hashCode` (see https://medium.com/qudini-engineering/400fd4547fe0). `LinkedList` doesn't sort, it just keeps the insertion order, so it won't use `compareTo`.

Comment: The truth is in the source. Or in javdoc, say for `LinkedList#contains` : "Returns true if this list contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))."

Comment: @DarshanMehta there is no guarantee OP would write code which exercises all relevant paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TreeMap` uses `compareTo`, and [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) warns you of problems if `compareTo` is not consistent with `equals` (i.e. that `a.compareTo(b) == 0 <=> a.equals(b)` should be true).

> Note that the ordering maintained by a tree map ... must be *consistent with equals* if this sorted map is to correctly implement the Map interface.

`LinkedList` uses `equals`.

---

The reason why `TreeMap` has to use an ordering consistent with `equals` is that the contract of `Map` defines the behavior in terms of `equals`. For example, [`containsKey`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey-java.lang.Object-) is defined as:

> returns `true` if and only if this map contains a mapping for a key `k` such that `(key==null ? k==null : key.equals(k))`

Let's say you define a class like this:

```
class Bad implements Comparable<Bad> {
  @Override public int compareTo(Bad other) { return 0; }
}
```

If you were to write:

```
Bad b1 = new Bad();
Bad b2 = new Bad();
```

Then:

```
Map<Bad, String> hm = new HashMap<>();
hm.put(b1, "");
System.out.println(hm.containsKey(b2));  // false
```

whereas

```
Map<Bad, String> tm = new TreeMap<>();
tm.put(b1, "");
System.out.println(tm.containsKey(b2));  // true
```

despite the fact that

```
System.out.println(tm.keySet().stream().anyMatch(k -> k.equals(b2))); // false
```

Thus, `TreeMap` violates the contract of `Map`, because `Bad` does not implement `Comparable` consistently with `equals`.

Answer (score 1):

The Javadoc of `TreeMap` and `LinkedList` answers this:

> **V java.util.TreeMap.get(Object key)**
>
> Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or null if this map contains no mapping for the key.
>
> More formally, if this map contains a mapping from a key k to a value v such that **key compares equal to k according to the map's ordering**, then this method returns v; otherwise it returns null. (There can be at most one such mapping.)

and

> **boolean java.util.LinkedList.contains(Object o)**
>
> Returns true if this list contains the specified element. More formally, **returns true if and only if this list contains at least one element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))**.

So, for `TreeMap` the Comparator\Comparable implementation is used to determine equality of keys, while for `LinkedList`s `equals` is used.

Comment: "compares equal according to the ordering" means compareTo==0, right? The doubt i have is, TreeMap NEVER uses equals and LinkedList NEVER uses compareTo, is this right?

Comment: Thanks. So why TreeMap gives warnings in case of unconsistency of compareTo and equals?

Comment: @GiuliaOrtali see https://medium.com/qudini-engineering/400fd4547fe0#cf06.

Comment: @GiuliaOrtali because it's up to you to implement `compareTo` and `equals` consistently. For example, if an object has two fields, `foo` and `bar`, equals might check both `foo` and `bar`, but `compareTo` might only check `bar`. That would yield different maps if you use `HashMap` vs `TreeMap`, because the contract of `Map` is defined in terms of `equals`.

Comment: Here they say that "if equals is not consistent with compareTo the TreeMap behave stragely", so this means that somewhere they use equals and you have to keep the two methods consistent, i think.

Comment: @GiuliaOrtali no, that's not what it means. It means that it gives inconsistent results with other implementations of `Map` if they're not consistent, because `Map`'s contract is defined in terms of `equals`.

Comment: Ok, i get it, Map uses equals but TreeMap uses compareTo. Thank you